# Waking a thread up from sleep when a collection is modified

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method that works on a queue. After consuming the first object in the queue, it goes to sleep for a predefined period (say 10 secs). Is there a way to wake that thread up if the queue is modified by any other thread on the 3rd or 4th second?

Comment: What do you mean by "goes to sleep" ? You use Thread.Sleep method or something else ?

Comment: Yes. I am using the Thread.Sleep method.

Comment: Yes, change your collection to `System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection`

Comment: Your problem is classic 'producer/consumer' problem, for example see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks, Alex and Servy. Will try out the producer/consumer approach and update the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the options you suggested. I finally settled on AutoResetEvent for this requirement. After consuming the first object in the queue, instead of putting the main thread to Sleep, I spawned a new thread from the main thread where I called sleep. The main thread would just wait. Once the new thread wakes up, it will signal the main thread using Set and the main thread will resume. That is one part.

The second part - If any other thread modifies the queue, even that thread will call Set on the same EventWaitHandle, thus again making the main thread to resume.

This might not be an optimal solution but simpler than other approaches.

Answer (score 7):

You should be using a collection specifically designed for such a purpose.  One example is `BlockingCollection`, which allows you to take an item from the collection and, if there are no items to take, the method will block until there is an item to give to you.  It is also a collection that is specifically designed to be manipulated from multiple threads, easing your burden on synchronization.

Note that `BlockingCollection` can be initialized so that it's backed with different types of collections.   By default it will use a `ConcurrentQueue`, but there are other collections in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace that you can use if you don't want queue semantics (it seems you do though).  You can also implement your own collection implementing `IProducerConsumerCollection<T>` if you really need something unique.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Thread.Sleep`:

You can use `Monitor.Wait` with a timeout and you can use `Monitor.Pulse`to wake it up if you need to from any thread.

[Really good example/explanation here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28785/Thread-synchronization-Wait-and-Pulse-demystified)

Answer (score 0):

In any case i'd recomend not to use `Thread.Sleep()` because it blocks thread completely.

It's much better to use `AutoResetEvent` or `ManualResetEvent` to synchronize two or more threads:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Servy has the correct answer for this using the [Blocking Collection](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_BlockingCollectionT).

Just to add further: It creates a new thread pooled thread when "work" items become available on the queue and processes them asynchronously on that thread.

You can use one in a producer/consumer queue:

E.g.:

```
/// <summary>
/// Producer/consumer queue. Used when a task needs executing, it’s enqueued to ensure order, 
/// allowing the caller to get on with other things. The number of consumers can be defined, 
/// each running on a thread pool task thread. 
/// Adapted from: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_BlockingCollectionT
/// </summary>
public class ProducerConsumerQueue : IDisposable
{
    private BlockingCollection<Action> _taskQ = new BlockingCollection<Action>();

    public ProducerConsumerQueue(int workerCount)
    {
        // Create and start a separate Task for each consumer:
        for (int i = 0; i < workerCount; i++)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Consume);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() 
    { 
        _taskQ.CompleteAdding(); 
    }

    public void EnqueueTask(Action action) 
    { 
        _taskQ.Add(action); 
    }

    private void Consume()
    {
        // This sequence that we’re enumerating will block when no elements
        // are available and will end when CompleteAdding is called.
        // Note: This removes AND returns items from the collection.
        foreach (Action action in _taskQ.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            // Perform task.
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would put the thread into a `while` iteration, then reduce the sleeptimer to something like 200 milliseconds.

But in every iteration I would check whether the queue was modified.
This way the Thread is constantly in the sleep-mode and kind of wakes up, when the queue was modified.

When you want to stop the thread you just set the `while` condition to `false`.